# Using 'preg_match' in PHP extracting variable from url

Tags: php, regex

Provide a regular expression that will extract the value of the u2 parameter from this url.
The regex matches will be extracted using the PHP function `preg_match` and will expect the match to either be the full regex extract, or the first capturing group.

Example: http://www.example.com?u1=US&u2=HA853&u3=HPA

Answer (score 1):

Instead of regular expressions, it’s more reliable and convenient to use [`parse_url()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) to parse URL and [`parse_str()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) to parse query string.

Comment: I did using parse_url() and parse_str(). But in this case, I want to use preg_match.

Comment: Using regular expressions is unreasonable when a proper parser is available. You could provide details on _why_ you want to use regular expressions instead of parser though.

Answer (score 0):

You could go for

```
<?php

$url = "Example: http://www.example.com?u1=US&u2=HA853&u3=HPA";

$regex = '~(?P<key>u\d+)=(?P<value>[^&]+)~';

preg_match_all($regex, $url, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
print_r($matches);
?>
```

Here, we are looking for `u`, followed by at least one digit, `=` and anything **not an ampersand**.